# How to check name already exist from first result array

Tags: codeigniter

i want to check cpt code is already exist in db or not in update form..

so,First i'm checking all cpt codes present in database except post one now i'm getting result without post cpt code....now I want check cpt code from first query result.

my function in controller

```
public function updatedDxCodeExist()
{
    $this->load->model('MedicineModel');
    $Id = $this->input->post("Id");
    $dxCode = $this->input->post("dxCode");

    if(empty($Id))
    {
        $result = $this->MedicineModel->updatedDxCodeExist($dxCode);
    } else {
        $result = $this->MedicineModel->updatedDxCodeExist($dxCode, $Id);
    }

    if(empty($result))
    {
        echo("true"); 
    }
    else 
    {
        echo("false"); 
    }
}
```

my function in model

```
public function updatedDxCodeExist($dxCode, $Id =0)
{
    $this->db->select("dx_code");
    $this->db->from("dx_codes");
    $this->db->where('dx_code !=',$dxCode);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: is there a question here?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use like this:

```
if($result->num_row() <= 0 )
{
    echo("true"); 
}
else 
{
    echo("false"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_search function in codeigniter